# Case function in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a basic question, when u use CASE with multiple values I Can use OR but I always have to repeat the name of the column = or there is a simpler solution see example below with phone numbers. Thanks for your tips.

```
 -- Channel Dial
   CASE
    WHEN FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS = '+3222011111' OR FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS   = '+3222018181'  THEN 'BCC'


    WHEN FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS  = '+3222012345' THEN 'MAIN'
    
    WHEN  FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS  = '3222785120' OR  FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS   =  '+3222785121' THEN 'Eshipper'

    ELSE 'OTHER'
  END AS "CHANNEL_DIAL",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE..WHEN` expression can be simplified using the `DECODE` as follows:

```
DECODE(FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS,
      '+3222011111','BCC',
      '+3222018181','BCC',
      '+3222012345','MAIN',
      '+3222785120','Eshipper',
      '+3222785121','Eshipper',
      'OTHER')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` keyword:

```
WHEN  FIS.TARGET_ADDRESS IN ('3222785120', '+3222785121') THEN
```